# Javascript: Detecting switching between environments

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working for a company that has the following environments:

- local.example.com
- staging.example.com
- approved-test.example.com
- www.example.com
- *and a few others that I can't list

Now, out of my control there are literally thousands of pages on each of these servers (They are massive) and there are a lot if absolutely defined links. And even if I could fix them in the code at the next code refresh it brings them all back.

So I'm trying to build a chrome extension that will allow me to detect when a link takes me out of an environment. Because i'm getting fed up of beign switched between them without realising.

At the moment I have have this:

```
function currentURL() {
        var result = {};
        var regexParse = new RegExp('([a-z\-0-9]{2,63})\.([a-z\.]{2,5})$');
        var urlParts = regexParse.exec(window.location.hostname);
        result.domain = urlParts[1];
        result.type = urlParts[2];
        result.subdomain = window.location.hostname.replace(result.domain + '.' + result.type, '').slice(0, -1);;
        return result.subdomain;
}
function nextURL(url) {

        var result = {};
        var regexParse = new RegExp('([a-z\-0-9]{2,63})\.([a-z\.]{2,5})$');
        var urlParts = regexParse.exec(url);
        result.domain = urlParts[1];
        result.type = urlParts[2];
        result.subdomain = window.location.hostname.replace(result.domain + '.' + result.type, '').slice(0, -1);;
        return result.subdomain;
}
```

and I get the `href` attribute of the url and compare to the current url.

My problem is this. Sometimes the link url passed over is just simply:

> /next-page

or maybe the outbound link is:

> //newexample.com

So, as you can see there are rather a few variations of what the next url could be.

JavaScript isn't my strongest skills so I ask you guys: What is the best way to check that the link I click is not external.

Answer (score 1):

> and I get the href attribute of the url and compare to the current url...

Don't use the `href` *attribute*, use the `href` *property*. The `href` *property* is a fully-resolved URL (when the URL can be fully resolved, which is usually).

So if you have a reference to the `HTMLAnchorElement` (the object for an `a` element) as `link`, for instance, use:

```
var url = link.href;
```

not

```
var url = link.getAttribute("href");
```

Here's an example of the difference:

```js
var link = document.querySelector("a[href]");
console.log("property:  " + link.href);
console.log("attribute: " + link.getAttribute("href"));
```

```html
Stack Snippets run in the domain <code>https://stacksnippets.net</code>. <a href="//stackoverflow.com">This link</a> is a protocol-relative link to Stack Overflow.
```